# OLTP - Stretch database vs linked server

Tags: sql-server, performance, linked-server, sql-server-2016, query-performance

From my understanding, when you enable the StretchDB feature for a table, basically creates a Linked Server locally, which has a remote server as a target to move data to.

If this is correct, does this mean that they will have the same problems? Such as:

- Getting all the data and then filtering after
- Terrible statistics on the data

[Kendra Little](https://www.littlekendra.com/) has a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AA_KqfXdV6Q) on Brent Ozar's [website](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/05/linked-servers-sql-server-performance-and-security-video/) outlining some of these problem.

Comment: Please elaborate on "the same problems".

Comment: Added the problems that I was talking @DanGuzman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has a different set of issues (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt605114.aspx) from the ones you listed.

First, it uses an external data source, not linked server. While functionally very similar, an external data source is a DB level object so it travels with the database. Linked servers are instance level objects that reside in master which require extra work when you need to move/restore a database with StretchDB enabled to another instance/server.

The stretch target is an Azure service powered by a SQL Server engine configured for StretchDB workloads. It's not just a file or blob. As such, query and predicate pushdown does occur so you are only pulling back what is already filtered by your query predicate, not the entire dataset. Else, this is useless right off the bat since it's intended to keep TBs of cold data. I'm sure edge cases exist where this doesn't work as intended but they should be very rare. Performance can still be bad but for some queries that are edge cases. E.g. you perform a nested loop join between a local and remote data sets. Some of these can be optimized or hinted but I'm sure there are cases where this isn't possible. For those, query performance can be really bad making them poor/non candidates for StretchDB.

As for statistics, it is currently a manual process to create and manage them but it's not a terribly hard to enable auto stats management in the engine so I'd imagine that shouldn't be too far in the future. Until then, you'll need to connect to the StretchDB database in Azure directly via SSMS/sqlcmd to create stats then update them at appropriate intervals.

Answer (score 0):

**Limitations for Stretch Database**

Not all tables will be eligible for being Stretch-enabled. Certain table properties, data and column types, constraints, and indexes are not supported, such as:

Memory-optimized and replicated tables
Tables that contain FILESTREAM data, use Change Tracking or Change Data
Data types such as timestamp, sql_variant, XML, geography or columns that are Always Encrypted
Check and default constraints or foreign key constraints that reference the table
XML, full-text, spatial, clustered columnstore and indexed views that reference the Stretch-enabled table
You cannot run UPDATE or DELETE statements, or run CREATE INDEX or ALTER INDEX operations on a Stretch-enabled table